# How to do a configuration on RMAN with run block without save this configuration on rman

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I want to do a run block with this configuration for test:

```
run {
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK MAXPIECESIZE 50M;
BACKUP DATABASE;
}
```

But I don't want that the configuration `CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK MAXPIECESIZE 50M` stay save on rman after of run the run block, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CONFIGURE`, just use `ALLOCATE` to allocate a channel with the desired parameters. You will also have to give a name for the channel, which is `C1` in the example here:

```
run {
ALLOCATE CHANNEL C1 DEVICE TYPE DISK MAXPIECESIZE 50M;
BACKUP DATABASE;
}
```